# Error on action_client as topic callback

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, rospy, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to implement a node that subscribes to a topic to get a list of  `geometry_msgs/Points` and then send it to `action_lib client` (implemented on the callback function of the subscriber) that communicate to the server.

I'm on ROS `Kinetic`.

Here are my subscriber:

```
  rospy.Subscriber(topic_name, topic_type,__goal_action_callback)
```

And my callback function:

```
  def __goal_action_callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(RobotMoving.get_name() + " " + "I heard {}".format(data))
    ac = SimpleActionClient("nav_server", NavigateAction)

    rospy.loginfo("goalCallback: Waiting for action server to start.")
    ac.wait_for_server()

    rospy.loginfo("goalCallback: Navigation service found.")

    goal = NavigateGoal

    goal.target_pos = data

    ac.send_goal_and_wait(goal)

    if ac.get_state() == GoalStatus.SUCCEEDED:
        rospy.loginfo("Navigate action is completed!")
    else:
        rospy.loginfo("Navigate action failed!")
```

Things are working fine for the first point read. However , for the second point and  further it gets this error:

```
[ERROR] [1518537259.290802, 30.718000]: bad callback: <function __goal_action_callback at 0x7fa5d05e5488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/bruno/rodain/src/rodain_get_directions/nodes/retrieve_content.py", line 27, in __goal_action_callback
    ac = SimpleActionClient("nav_server", NavigateAction)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actionlib/simple_action_client.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.action_client = ActionClient(ns, ActionSpec)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/actionlib/action_client.py", line 519, in __init__
    raise ActionException("Type is not an action spec: %s" % str(ActionSpec))
ActionException: Type is not an action spec: <class 'move_quadcopter.msg._NavigateAction.NavigateAction'>
```

It seems to me that relys on  how things are done on background.
Anyone know why it is happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282605/error-on-action_client-as-topic-callback/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ActionException: Type is not an action spec: <class 'move_quadcopter.msg._NavigateAction.NavigateAction'>
> ```

It's likely that the following statement in your callback is the problem:

```
goal = NavigateGoal
```

You're setting `goal` equal to the `NavigateGoal` *class*, not to an instance of it (ie: an object).

Try changing the line to:

```
goal = NavigateGoal()
```

and see whether that works any better.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on 2018-02-13**:
the way i've done the subscriber function will get one Point than invoke the callback or it will get all the Points and after i have all call the callback? For me seems it's getting one-by-one but I don't know why.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
Your callback will be called for *each incoming message*, so for `N` msgs, you will submit `N` goals to your action server.